# AFNetworking and 304 NotModified returns error

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

When querying my webservice with i.e Postman Rest Client, with the If-Modified-Since I get correct response with 304 and no data in the content.

However, when I am doing this from my app, I get the following error:

Error: Request failed: not modified (304), got 256

This is how I am initializing the request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:@"myUrl" relativeToURL:[baseURL absoluteString] parameters:nil];

self = [self initWithRequest:request];

[request setValue:modifyDate forHTTPHeaderField:@"If-Modified-Since"];
```

This is my operation:

```
[self setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON)
 {
     DLog(@"Response: %@", [operation responseString]);

     int statusCode = operation.response.statusCode;
     if(statusCode == 304) //NotModified
     {
         DLog(@"This is where i want to go");
     }
     success();
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     DLog(@"ERROR RESPONSE: %@", [operation responseString]);
     DLog(@"This is where I get");
 }];
```

The responseString in the error-block is emtpy.

This is what the error gives when I print it:

```
Printing description of error:
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: not modified (304), got 256" UserInfo=0x8a7dd10 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://myApiUrl, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8acc5e0> { URL: http://10.225.80.63/api/getAllRegionsAndCancertypes } { status code: 304, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Date = "Thu, 20 Feb 2014 10:23:10 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not modified (304), got 256}
```

What am I missing? The status seems to be correct even in the error block, but why do I get there at all?

Thank you!

Comment: The code 304 is already use by AFNetworking and mean (Data not Modified) then you can look in your cache to get the data. But that cannot be a success with the code 304.

Comment: So there should be an error when the response is 304?

Comment: Will only status code 200 go to the success-block then?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that should be the only one.

Comment: This is a clear demonstration of a poor design choice in AFNetworking.  While it can be convenient to let AFNetworking decide whether you have received an error or not, it should be up to the client to decide whether an error has occurred.  HTTP status codes are subtle gradations, not binary choices.  AFNetworking would be simplified by simply having completion blocks rather than dual success/failure blocks.

Answer (score 4):

By default AFNetworking treats only 200 as success, but there is a way to specify the status codes that should be treated as success. You can do this using response serialization, here is the code

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

AFHTTPResponseSerializer *respSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
NSMutableIndexSet *responseCodes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
[responseCodes addIndex:200];
[responseCodes addIndex:304];
respSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = responseCodes;

[operation setResponseSerializer:respSerializer];
```

with this code AFNetworking will treat 304 as success and it will call the success block.

Comment: Tried to edit this in, but got rejected. Horray!! : "respSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = responseCodes;"

Comment: I've added it in for you @Spoek

Answer (score 2):

I want to propose my own variant of solving this problem. If you use AFNetworking 3.0 and work with AFHTTPSessionManager in request's singletone class:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *sessionManager = ...
...
NSMutableIndexSet *responseCodes = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] initWithIndexSet:sessionManager.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes];
// Add code 304 in 'success list'
[responseCodes addIndex:304];

sessionManager.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = responseCodes;
...
```

This approach does not violate responseSerializer configuration (if you use AFJSONResponseSerializer for example).